# Laravel different Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question regarding Middlewares.
So right now I created 3 Middlewares called Admin, Office and User.
This is the CustomerController:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{


public function getAllCustomer()
{
    return Customer::get();
}

public function addNewCustomer(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'Title' => 'required',
        'Name' => 'required|max:255',
        'Surname' => 'required|max:255',
        'Email' => 'required',
        'Phone' => 'required',
        'Password' => 'required',
        'dateofBirth' => 'required'
    ]);

    return \app\model\Customer::create($request->all());
}


public function update (Request $request , Customer $id)
{
    $id->update($request->all());
}


public function destroy (Customer $id)
{
    $id->delete();
}
```

The Customer is able to read, create, update and to delete.
But right now I want to use a Middleware, so that only the admin is able to create/read/update/delete all the data, the user and is only able to to this with his own data.
So right now I have 3 Middleware classes and I added this to the Kernel.php:

```
'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthentification::class',
 'office' => 'App\Http\Middleware\OfficeAuthentification::class',
 'user' => 'App\Http\Middleware\UserAuthentification::class'
```

My question is:
What do I Need to add in the Middleware to add the fuction I described?

Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: what is your question?? You missed it

Comment: You need to use [gates / policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#gates) not middleware for this. Good Luck!

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam I added my main question, I want to know what I Need to add in the Middleware to add the function I described.

Comment: you can check the user type in each middleware and if it doesn't matches your specified user type than you can do  `abort(403);` other wise do nothing.

Comment: and you also need to apply middleware on routes or in controller `__construct()` method

Comment: @tayyab_fareed Could you write me an example please how to implement this on my work?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Ross Wilson Im using Laravel 5.6.29

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a very ugly way of doing things but anyhow... You should checkout `gates/policies` or something like [spatie/laravel](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission).

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class UserAuthentification {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(check user type){
       //allowed
    }
    else{
        //forbidden
        //you can abort
        abort(403);

    }

    $response = $next($request);

    return $response;
}

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, but what do you mean with "check user type"? There is only one user type, it can either be an user or not. There is the user, admin and Office.

Comment: Its up to your database structure and relations that you have defined you can get `user` with `$request->user()` but I don't know how did you define the user type

Comment: So I Need to create a user model? I have a customer model, which has Attributes like Name, surname, zip etc. Right now I didnt define a user type

Comment: How do you know if the logged in person is user, admin or office?